# Instrumentation amplifier - schematic review

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm trying to make an instrumentation amplifier to measure a sine wave signal of 0 - 1Vpp (max) 50Hz that comes from a non-invasive current sensor (30A SCT-013-030). It gives 1Vpp at 30A current.

This is the circuit I made. The output goes to an MCU.

[image]

According to this note, my circuit with the selected values should have GAIN = 3.
[image]

I would like to know if this circuit is okay for that kind of application.

Also, I found on the internet that in AC-coupled signals require a common-mode voltage applied to both inputs of the circuit. And that voltage should be the less of the maximum value of the signal which in my case would be 0.5V
[image]
Do I need that voltage in my case?
What does it do exactly?

[Link to the schematics](https://www.edn.com/the-right-way-to-use-instrumentation-amplifiers/)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I posted the link

Comment: Which microcontroller you are using? ATMEGA 16, 32 (I used these two) have differential amplifiers in it.

Comment: If precision and common mode suppression are important, you should consider a dedicated instrumentation amplifier.  Those have laser-trimmed matched resistors on-chip.

Answer (score 1):

AC coupling would make your current reading frequency related. The transformer has to have somehow a reference potential, i.e not floating. If you have a single supply, then it should be biased to Vref/2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frFphs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As said, best way is to have DC coupled signal with anti-alias filter. You will have a DC offset, that you can eliminate it with high sampling and HF pass digital filter (for example > 20 Hz pass). In such way you have all harmonics with true amplitude, no need to re calibrate for 50/60Hz.